# matlab compile to C: detect slbuild vs coder

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink, matlab-coder

Apparently `slbuild` has severe limitations on the size of arrays that it supports. MATLAB Coder gives me options to convert those to dynamic memory. I don't see how to do that with 'slbuild'. However, I need to run both exports. We use the MATLAB Coder output where it matters, and the nice models produced with slbuild in unit tests. To make this happen I need to change some sizes based upon the build system. How do I do this?

```
classdef MyFilter
  properties (Constant)
     maxArraySizeDim1 = 3000 if slbuild or simulink is running else 65535;
     maxArraySizeDim2 = 3000 if slbuild or simulink is running else 65535;
```

Can I set some variable before calling `slbuild` or `codegen` and use it here?

Comment: Are your targets different in Simulink and MATLAB? If so you can try coder.target function.

Comment: How can I output `coder.target` during a compilation?

Comment: It may not be available at class load time which is when Constant properties are initialized. But if you have a method to get the max size, you can use coder.target in that conditionally to return different values.